# Where is the Write Protection Screw On this Board hp chromebook 14a-na0031wm

Tags: chromebook

[Click Here for Motherboard Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqCv4.jpg)

Please help me if you can tell where the write protection screw is on this board.

hp chromebook 14a-na0031wm

Thank You

Comment: What makes you think you need this screw? It is not mentioned in any of your manuals... https://support.hp.com/gb-en/product/hp-chromebook-14a-na0000-series/32708668/manuals

Comment: write protection of what?

Comment: did you just start a new job?

Answer (score 1):

There is no write protect screw on this model.
Are you trying to install Windows?

Comment: It's usually people trying to bypass school restrictions. They read about some hack from 6 or 8 years ago & wonder why it no longer works ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Good point. To that I can relate.

Comment: Hi and thanks mr. Gantendo, I would like to install windows on my Chromebook... It is just telling me that there is a wp (write protection) in my bios

Comment: @reaction this site is not well suited for what you need as hacking around on a chrome book is going to be very in depth. Somewhere like https://mrchromebox.tech/#devices seems far more suitable, but first you would have to establish exactly what your device is and whether you can get a UEFI firmware on it, which would be a prerequisite to installing Windows.

Comment: A quick glance there suggests that newer devices indeed lack the WP switch or screw and other methods are required that are of varying complexity and that once you have done that there are still steps to go. In that at least the answer is most likely correct, that you do not have a WP screw.